# Jinja2 '-' in variable, bug?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making my first steps at flask, I'm trying to make custom html tags with wtf-forms

when i use this:

```
{{form.email(data-trigger="hover")}}
```

i got this:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got '='
```

without it everything works:

```
{{form.email(datatrigger="hover")}}
```

is there any way to fix it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779024/setting-data-attributes-on-a-wtforms-field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779024/setting-data-attributes-on-a-wtforms-field)

Answer (score 6):

Identifiers in Python (including Python snippets embedded in Jinja2) can include letters, underscores, and digits (and can't start with a digit).

Other punctuation, including dashes, are **not** allowed in identifiers  (not a Python peculiarity -- many other languages have exactly the same lexical rules for what's allowed in an identifier).

So **no**, there is **no** way to "fix" Python to allow you to include a dash (which Python takes as a "minus" operator) within an identifier.  Why would you need to?  Can't you use, e.g, an underscore instead?

Comment: In this instance, underscores can be used as WTForms will convert the underscore to a hyphen when rendering the `input` tag. `form.email(data_trigger='...')` will become `<input data-trigger="..." ... >`.

Comment: thank you alot, it works! i think i need to read documentation more accurate